# error on switching layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to switch the layout but the error below keeps coming up.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.setId(int)' on a null object reference
```

android studio is complaining on "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"

I'm not sure how to fix this error. I googled just the error and tried several of the fixes but none worked with the thread for networking added. I'm probably just missing something simple. Any help is much appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ChatServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            client = new Client();
            client.start();
            Network.register(client);
            client.addListener(new Listener() {
                public void connected(Connection connection) {
                    Network.RegisterName registerName = new Network.RegisterName();
                    registerName.name = name;
                    client.sendTCP(registerName);
                }

                public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
                    if (object instanceof Network.ChatMessage) {
                        Network.ChatMessage chatMessage = (Network.ChatMessage) object;
                        System.out.println(chatMessage.text);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
            host = client.discoverHosts(54777, 5000);
            while (host == null) {
                host = client.discoverHosts(54777, 5000);
                System.out.println(host);
            }
            if (host.isEmpty()) {
                addmsg("no hosts available");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            final InetAddress address = host.get(0);
            setContentView(R.layout.promptname);
        }
    }).start();




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` outside your anonymous-inner thread class, and get rid of  `setContentView(R.layout.promptname);` You need to switch between views, you should look into `Fragment`

Comment: that fixed it. what is the best way to switch layouts? i still need to switch to the promptname layout

Comment: you should use two different `Fragment`s. You could try the `ViewSwitcher`, but I never used it and I think the `Fragment` approach is always better